# How to show a specific function has a unique root?

Tags: calculus, roots

Let $f(x)=\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+3\right) \log \left(\frac{x+3}{4}\right)-\sqrt{x} \log (x)}{\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)^3 \sqrt{x}}$, where $x>0$ and the $\log$ is the natural logarithm (with base $e$). My question is how to show that it has a unique root.

I tried many ways, such as taking its derivative. However, its derivative appears to be even more complicated and intractable.

I also know that $x=9$ is a root but have no idea how to show its uniqueness.

I also plotted the function, however, this is not a proof anyway.

[image]

Comment: You can try with the intermediate value since the function is continuous. Show that the function is antitone to the minimum and then isotone but the limit for infinity is smaller than zero.

Comment: $x=1$ is a root of your equation.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, $x=1$ is not a root. $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=1/16$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner At $x=1$ the numerator becomes zero.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria I tried to show what you mentioned by taking the derivative of $f$. However, the derivative looks even more intractable. $f'(x)=\frac{6 \left(x^{3/2}-2 x+\sqrt{x}\right)-3 \left(4 x^{3/2}+x^2+2 x+12 \sqrt{x}-3\right) \log \left(\frac{x+3}{4}\right)+3 x (x+3) \log (x)}{2 \left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)^4 x^{3/2} (x+3)}$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=\frac 18$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you are right. It is $1/8$.

Comment: When $x$ is large, $f(x) \sim -\frac{2\log(2)}{x^{3/2}}$

Answer (score 2):

Your graph is a good hint.  As $x$ gets very large the denominator always is positive, so you just need to prove that the numerator stays negative.
$$(\sqrt x + 3)\log\left(\frac {x+3}4 \right)-\sqrt x \log x=(\sqrt x+3)(\log (x+3)-\log 4)-\sqrt x\log x\\=(\sqrt x+3)\log x\left(\log (1+\frac 3x)-\frac {\log 4}{\log x}\right)-\sqrt x\log x\\\approx (\sqrt x+3)\log x\left(\frac 3x-\frac {\log 4}{\log x} \right)-\sqrt x\log x\\ \lt 0$$
The denominator is getting large faster which is why the function approaches zero, but it won't get there because the numerator is always negative for $x$ large.

Comment: What about small $x$?

Comment: Why does $\log(x+3)$ equal $\log(x)\cdot\log(1+\frac3x)$ in your second step because it is in general not true (e.g. $x=1$)?

Comment: @HazemOrabi:  I assumed OP had searched the small regime based on the graph but a good question.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria:  It is a law of logarithms as long as $x \neq 1$.  I was working for large $x$, so it is not a problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for your answer. I tried but couldn't find a way to show that there is a unique root when $x$ is small :-(

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sqrt(x)%2B3)log((x%2B3)%2F4)-sqrt(x)log(x)%3D0) says the only roots for the numerator being zero are $1,9$.  The function is not defined at $1$.  We only care about roots of the numerator, but you can't do the $\approx$ sign in my derivation for small $x$

Comment: @RossMillikan how to show that 1 and 9 are only root?

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, I realize that Alpha is a link. Unfortunately, I couldn't see the step-by-step solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan I purchased WolframAlpha pro to see the step-by-step solution. However, it said "Oops, we don't have a step-by-step solution for this query. Send us feeback about how you'd like to see step-by-step solutions grow."

Comment: When you graph the numerator it is clear that $9$ is a separated root.  The area around $1$ is harder.  You can take the [derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+(sqrt(x)%2B3)log((x%2B3)%2F4)-sqrt(x)log(x)) and see it is positive near $1$ so you don't come back to the axis.